# Java program not outputting correct integer value

Tags: java, integer-division

I am attempting to run a program through my main() class in my CelsiusToFahrenheit.java file. I created a public class called CelsiusToFahrenheit and when the class receives a parameter of the type "double" it is supposed to take that input and run it through an algorithm that converts the Celsius number in to Fahrenheit. When I compile the code and input an integer the output doesn't reflect the algorithm assigned to tempOutput. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CelsiusToFahrenheit {
   public static double convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(double tempInput) {
      double tempOutput = 0.0;
      tempOutput = (tempInput * (9 / 5)) + 32;
      return tempOutput;
}


   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double tempF = 0.0;
      double tempC = 0.0;

      System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
      tempC = scnr.nextDouble();

      tempF = convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(tempC);

      System.out.print("Fahrenheit: ");
      System.out.println(tempF);

      scnr.close();

      return;
   }
}
```

Any given number I input for the tempC variable outputs tempC + 32 when it is supposed to multiply tempC by 1.8 and then add 32 to it. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: But this is discrete since you used `(` `)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tempOutput = (tempInput * (9 / 5)) + 32;` - `9/5=1` because it's integer division. You can use `9/5.0` or `(tempInput * 9 / 5) + 32;` for using float division. The second way will work, because java is left to right and `double*int` will be a `double`, and `double/int` will use float division.

I'll also add a remark, that your class should be probably called `TemperatureConverter` instead of `CelsiusToFahrenheit`. Why? Because your current name closes you to the improvements. You shouldn't implement `farenheitToCelsius` in this class which you might want to do in the future.

Comment: Or remove the `(` `)` will do it to. The operation `double * int / int ` will be ok. PS : I had added an answer on the duplicate yesterday using JLS reference to explain how this work. Still need some hint to improve this I think.